# How use a module function with Ajax when onchange a input in Drupal 7

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

I have a function in my drupal module that update a shop basket, i need that when change the quantity in a input, this funcion will be launch by Ajax.

In the case

```
<a href='/my_module/route/nojs' class='use-ajax'>
```

I only use the class "use-ajax" provided by Chaos tool module, but I dont know how use in a javascript onchange:

```
<input type='number' onchange='ajax_function(this.value)'>
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can add onblur event on input field and call ajax request.
For ex:

For above implementation please follow below steps :

1. create hook_menu

   `/**`

   - Implements hook_menu().
   - @return array
     */

   function mymodule_menu() {
     $items['itg-custom-callback'] = array(
       'page callback' => 'itg_custom_callback',
       'access callback' => true,
       'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     );
     return $items;
   }

   function itg_custom_callback() {
     do your code here
   }

Add js file in menu

```
jQuery('.quantity').onBlur(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + "/itg-custom-callback",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {},
                    beforeSend: function () {

                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                });

            });
```